# Make windows automatically start an application again when it suddenly closed

Tags: windows, application-launch, runtime-error

I have windows form application running in Windows, but it sometimes crashes randomly.

Can we set it to automatically run again when it it closed? I need the application to always be running.

Comment: You can probably write a program that runs in the background and checks if the process you're interested in is running and start it if it isn't. [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes) is an example code in C++ that checks which processes are running, you might be able to rewrite it to do what you want.